# How is the interface being instantiated, without implementation of any class?

Tags: java, interface, instantiation, bluej

```
public interface InterfaceTest {
    interface Gift  { void present(); }
    interface Guest { void present(); }
    interface Presentable extends Gift, Guest { }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Presentable johnny = new Presentable() {
                @Override public void present() {
                    System.out.println("Heeeereee's Johnny!!!");
                }
            };
        johnny.present();                     
        ((Gift) johnny).present();            
        ((Guest) johnny).present();           
        Gift johnnyAsGift = (Gift) johnny;
        johnnyAsGift.present();              
        Guest johnnyAsGuest = (Guest) johnny;
        johnnyAsGuest.present();
    }
}
```

This code compiles and runs the main() function without error, what concept am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

`johnny` is an instance of an [anonymous subclass](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html). From the link:

> Anonymous classes enable you to make your code more concise. They
> enable you to declare and instantiate a class at the same time. They
> are like local classes except that they do not have a name. Use them
> if you need to use a local class only once.

The reason your code compiles is because the implementation of `present` is provided in this anonymous subclass. To drive the point further, this:

```
Presentable johnny = new Presentable();
```

would not compile. However, this:

```
Presentable johnny = new Presentable() {
    @Override public void present() {
         // Do something
    }
};
```

is perfectly valid.